# Motor control using arduino board

Tags: motor, voltage-level

I want to control 2 dc motors using the arduino board directly. One motor must rotate clockwise and the other counter clockwise. The directions  doesn't change only the speed of each motors. Can this be done without any shield? Them motors may need a higher voltage than the arduino can provide. If I link the arduino board to a power source of about 15 V (the board is arduino mega limits between 6 and 20 ) and I use "analog.write()" function can I output more than 5 volts(the internal voltage)?

Comment: If you post a link to the motors you are intending to drive, you might get an even simpler solution. We need to know both the voltage and the current, preferably from the motor's datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is two MOSFETs (one per motor, because you don't need to change direction), and some miscellaneous passives, and a flyback diode for each motor.

See [this tutorial](http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/) for wiring diagrams and details.

Comment: Great link! You saved me! But I still don't get it. What's the difference between a mosfet and a transistor? I searcher a few more pages and they said a mosfet is a transistor. Does any transistor work?

Comment: A MOSFET is a type of transistor. BJTs (bipolar junction transistors) are the other dominant type of transistor, and are not as appropriate for this application. The difference between MOSFETs and BJTs is too much to discuss here, but as far as what you should use: use a logic-level MOSFET (low Vgs(on))

Comment: @uint128_t it is syaing that link does not exist